# File is not found in for uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload excel file into sql database through the following code in server

I am able to open the excel file in the server but I am not able to upload this file in to sql through asp page. it shows nor file found even though I select the file through file browser control . file name is displaying on the screen when I browsed .But when I click the upload button it is not found.Please help me

My C# code is this

```
   protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (fileuploadExcel.HasFile)
        {
           SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(str);
        //file upload path


        string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;


        //Create connection string to Excel work book
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
        //Create Connection to Excel work book
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Date],[PName],[SQE Reived],[SQE processed] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn1);
        //Give your Destination table name
        conn1.Open();
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "SQE";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

My asp page macrkup

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Upload Productivity data in to iConnect"     runat="server" CssClass="style88"  
                     Font-Bold="False" Height="36px" Width="750px" Font-        Names="Calibri" ForeColor="White" Font-Size ="large"   Border-radius="0px 0px 0px 0px"
                                       ></asp:Button>

   </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <a href="SQEprTemplate.xlsx">Download Template for upload</a>

    <br />
     <br />

 </td>

 <tr>
 <td>
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
         <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadExcel" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
           onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
        <br/>

     </asp:Panel>


 </td>

 </tr>



 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Try uploading the file first as Steve mentioned. His example also covers the issue which Grant Winney mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain `path` will already contain the drive letter, but you're appending `D:\\` to the beginning of it on the next line.

```
... Source=D:\\" + path ...
```

Try removing `D:\\`

Comment: My code is not entering into if (fileuploadExcel.HasFile).

Answer (score 0):

[`fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the name, complete of path, on the **Client** machine.
This file is not present in the server machine, you need to save it before trying to use it

```
string serverFolder = Server.MapPath("APP_DATA");
string serverFile = Path.Combine(serverFolder, Path.GetFileName(fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName));
fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.SaveAs(serverFile);
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                               @"Data Source=" + serverFile + 
                               @";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
```